# How can I click on a customer's name and present just their name in an actionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

[image]

Right now, with this MVC project I am running. I have a table of two customers that are hard coded into the table without using a database. The two images below show what is supposed to happen when you click on one of the customers. It will pull up the following URL "Customers/Details/1" using an action result Details while displaying the id of that customer. Since there are only two customers, if you change the url to "Customers/Details/3", it would return HttpNotFound error. I have included my customers controller, viewmodel for the table and route config file. When I click on one of the customers I get "The view 'details' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        
        // GET: customer/getCustomer
        public ActionResult Index() 
        {
           
           
               //Create instance of movie
                
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer {Name = "John Smith"},
                new Customer {Name = "Jane Doe"}
            };

            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel
            {
                 Customers = customers
            };
                return View(viewModel);

         }
        
       public ActionResult details(int id)
       {
            

            if (customers == null)
               return HttpNotFound();
            else
                return View(viewModel);





        } 
    }
}
```

```
@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (Model.Customers.Count == 0)
{
    <text>There are no customers</text>
}
else 
{
<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "details", new {id = 1 }, null)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    
    namespace WebApplication1
    {
        public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                     "Customers",
                     "Customer/details/{id}",
                     new { controller = "Customer", action = "details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
    
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the real code for the `details` action please? What you have shown doesn't compile.

Comment: That is the real code, I am not sure what to put for that actionResult

Comment: I believe it is something with my actionResult details and my route config that is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of the problem is that you're hardcoding things, rather than storing things somewhere, but I'll do the same for the sake of an example.

Firstly, at the top of your controller, add the following `using` directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Change your action to:

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // Remember that this is a different copy of the list
    // to the one in the Index action.
    var customers = new List<Customer>
    {
        // Notice I've added an Id property.
        new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "John Smith"},
        new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe"}
    };

    // Attempt to find a customer whose Id property is
    // equal to the id passed to the action.
    // SingleOrDefault() states that we expect to find only
    // one match if there is one, and if there isn't, it'll return `null`.
    var customer = customers
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (customer == null)
    {
        // Alternatively, you could return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return NotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
    {
        Customer = customer;
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Finally, take a look at the routes you've defined:

```
"Customer/details/{id}"
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Notice, `Customer` is the name of your controller, and `details` is the name of your action, and they both define an `id` parameter. That means that route already matches the default `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` route, and so you don't need your `Customers` route.

As for your comment about the details view, your folder structure should look like this:

```
Views
  \ Home
     \ Index.cshtml
  \ Customer
     \ Index.cshtml
     \ Details.cshtml
```

At this point though, I would strongly recommend working through some MVC tutorials, as it seems you're currently missing some of the fundamentals.

Comment: @Soccerplayer97 Let me update my answer a bit to show you where it should be - it's a little difficult to format in a comment.

Comment: I believe I have found the correct solution, I was able to go through some tutorials a couple days ago. My route didn't need to be modified at all and I needed to create to separate view models for my customers and movies view. Is there a way I could share my source code with you or would I have to edit this post?

Comment: @Soccerplayer97 I'm really sorry for the late reply - it's been a tough week. For questions like that, you can post on codereview.stackexchange.com. That way, you can feedback from multiple sources.